# Constructor for a subclass of List<T> C#

Tags: c#, list, class, constructor, initialization

This is my class:

```
public class CustomList: List<SomeType>{

 SomeType myList;

 public CustomList(List<SomeType> list){
  myList = list;
 }

//some methods
}
```

and I initialise it like this:

```
CustomList myCustomList = new CustomList(someList);
```

However upon accessing the first member of the list (`myCustomList[0]`) i get:
AurgumentOutOfRangeException error.

Am I doing anything wrong in my custom list constructor and/or initialisation?

Appreciate your help.

Edit:

SomeType is a class consist of some public variables:

```
public class SomeType{
 public string title;
 public string campaign;
}
```

Comment: I don't see where you are adding to the `List<>`.  You can access your .ctor argument value via `myCustomList.myList` if `myList` is public.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you want the .ctor argument to be added to the list.  So add it...

```
public class CustomList: List<SomeType>{

 public CustomList(List<SomeType> list){
  this.AddRange(list);
 }

//some methods
}
```

As Alexei pointed out in the comments an alternative method of calling the base class .ctor using this syntax in C#:

```
public class CustomList : List<SomeType> {
    public CustomList(List<SomeType> list) : base(list) { ... }
}
```

Comment: You are right, but `list` is not a List - as my code comment points out.

Comment: @Kourosh So now you need `this.AddRange(list)` :)

Comment: `base(list)` would be better... but `AddRange` is ok too.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: so... `public CustomList(List<SomeType> list) : base(list) { ... }` ?

Comment: Could you please tell me how can you cast List<SomeType> to SomeType?

Comment: @SamAxe - yes. I think calling matching base class constructor better expresses intention (unless there actually need for some additional processing/filtering of arguments to base constructor).